# Prove that for a square matrix A: $Im\left(A^{\top}\right)=Ker(A)^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

**Question:**

Let $A$ be a square matrix.
Show that:
$$
Im\left(A^{\top}\right)=Ker(A)^{\perp}
$$
**My take:**

I was going for bi-directional inclusion.

The first direction is easy.

Let $v\in Im\left(A^{T}\right)$, so there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ such that $A^{T}x=v$.

Let $w\in Ker\left(A\right)$, then:
$$
\left\langle v,w\right\rangle =\left\langle A^{T}x,w\right\rangle =\left\langle x,Aw\right\rangle =\left\langle x,0\right\rangle =0
$$
and we get that $Im\left(A^{T}\right)\subseteq Ker\left(A\right)^{\perp}$.

---

I need help with showing that $Ker\left(A\right)^{\perp}\subseteq Im\left(A^{T}\right)$, I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Both sets are finite-dimensional vector subspaces, so once you established inclusion, you can check whether the dimensions are equal. The calculation is easy and uses the rank-nullity theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
v \in \text{Ker }A &\Leftrightarrow A v = 0\\
&\Leftrightarrow \langle A v, w\rangle = 0 \quad \forall w \in \mathbb R^m\\
&\Leftrightarrow \langle  v, A^T w\rangle = 0 \quad \forall w \in \mathbb R^m\\
&\Leftrightarrow v \in \text{Im }(A^T)^\perp
\end{align}
so that $\text{Ker }A = \text{Im }(A^T)^\perp$ and $\text{Ker }(A)^\perp = \text{Im }(A^T)$.